# Bazel rules_foreign_cc - using cmake binary built from source at build time

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to run a Bazel build that uses rules_foreign_cc's cmake_external rule. My understanding is that by passing the proper arguments to the rules_foreign_cc_dependencies(...) workspace function, I can instruct the build to use a prebuilt version of cmake instead of using the cmake installed locally on the build server.

I've tried to following to no avail:

```
rules_foreign_cc_dependencies(
    ["//:built_cmake_toolchain"],
    False,
)
```

where `built_cmake_toolchain` is defined as follows:

```
toolchain(
    name = "built_cmake_toolchain",
    exec_compatible_with = [
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:osx",
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:x86_64",
    ],
    toolchain = "@rules_foreign_cc//tools/build_defs/native_tools:built_cmake",
    toolchain_type = "@rules_foreign_cc//tools/build_defs:cmake_toolchain",
)
```

, but I get a "no matching toolchains found for types @rules_foreign_cc//tools/build_defs:cmake_toolchain" error during the build.

Does anybody know how to use a non locally installed version of cmake when using rules_foreign_cc's external_cmake rule?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might also need the ninja tool or tools for the Linux platform. I've had luck with this config:

**WORKSPACE**

```
rules_foreign_cc_dependencies(
    native_tools_toolchains = [
        ":built_cmake_toolchain_linux",
        ":built_cmake_toolchain_osx",
        ":built_ninja_toolchain_linux",
        ":built_ninja_toolchain_osx",
    ],
    register_default_tools = False,
)
```

**BUILD**

```
toolchain(
    name = "built_cmake_toolchain_linux",
    exec_compatible_with = [
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:linux",
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:x86_64",
    ],
    toolchain = "@rules_foreign_cc//tools/build_defs/native_tools:built_cmake",
    toolchain_type = "@rules_foreign_cc//tools/build_defs:cmake_toolchain",
)

toolchain(
    name = "built_cmake_toolchain_osx",
    exec_compatible_with = [
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:osx",
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:x86_64",
    ],
    toolchain = "@rules_foreign_cc//tools/build_defs/native_tools:built_cmake",
    toolchain_type = "@rules_foreign_cc//tools/build_defs:cmake_toolchain",
)

toolchain(
    name = "built_ninja_toolchain_linux",
    exec_compatible_with = [
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:linux",
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:x86_64",
    ],
    toolchain = "@rules_foreign_cc//tools/build_defs/native_tools:built_ninja",
    toolchain_type = "@rules_foreign_cc//tools/build_defs:ninja_toolchain",
)

toolchain(
    name = "built_ninja_toolchain_osx",
    exec_compatible_with = [
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:osx",
        "@bazel_tools//platforms:x86_64",
    ],
    toolchain = "@rules_foreign_cc//tools/build_defs/native_tools:built_ninja",
    toolchain_type = "@rules_foreign_cc//tools/build_defs:ninja_toolchain",
)
```